# how to duplicate the message in data table pdf document all pages

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using data table export functions like PDF and Excel. In PDF export I have message option, which is showing in only one page of document. But I want that in every page of the document.

```
{
 extend: 'pdfHtml5',
 message:" Phase:  Phase1",
 filename: 'Tickets_List',
 footer: true,
 header:true,
}
```

please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After examination of the DataTables & pdfMake docs, you can't change the title on each page, but you can get rid of it.

I suggest you use the header attribute as you can change the size and font, and change it per page.

The following example shows the header in the same position as the title, with a customize function:

**UPDATE**

For some reason, you cannot download the PDF from a SO Code Snippet, so here is a working fiddle as well https://jsfiddle.net/BeerusDev/tb3zy0us/30/

```js
var dataSet = [
    [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
    [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
    [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
    [ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
    [ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ],
    [ "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000" ],
    [ "Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500" ],
    [ "Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900" ],
    [ "Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500" ],
    [ "Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600" ],
    [ "Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560" ],
    [ "Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000" ],
    [ "Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600" ],
    [ "Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500" ],
    [ "Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750" ],
    [ "Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500" ],
    [ "Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000" ],
    [ "Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500" ],
    [ "Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000" ],
    [ "Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500" ],
    [ "Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000" ],
    [ "Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000" ],
    [ "Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450" ],
    [ "Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sydney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600" ],
    [ "Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000" ],
    [ "Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575" ],
    [ "Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650" ],
    [ "Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850" ],
    [ "Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000" ],
    [ "Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000" ],
    [ "Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sydney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400" ],
    [ "Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500" ],
    [ "Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000" ],
    [ "Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500" ],
    [ "Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050" ],
    [ "Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675" ],
      [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
    [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
    [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
    [ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
    [ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ],
    [ "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000" ],
    [ "Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500" ],
    [ "Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900" ],
    [ "Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500" ],
    [ "Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600" ],
    [ "Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560" ],
    [ "Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000" ],
    [ "Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600" ],
    [ "Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500" ],
    [ "Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750" ],
    [ "Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500" ],
    [ "Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000" ],
    [ "Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500" ],
    [ "Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000" ],
    [ "Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500" ],
    [ "Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000" ],
    [ "Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000" ],
    [ "Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450" ],
    [ "Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sydney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600" ],
    [ "Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000" ],
    [ "Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575" ],
    [ "Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650" ],
    [ "Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850" ],
    [ "Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000" ],
    [ "Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000" ],
    [ "Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sydney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400" ],
    [ "Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500" ],
    [ "Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000" ],
    [ "Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500" ],
    [ "Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050" ],
    [ "Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675" ]
];
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ],
        dom: 'Brptif',
        buttons: [
          {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            title: null,
            footer: true,
            header:true,
                        customize: function(doc) {
            doc['header'] = (function(page, pages) {
            return {
            margin: [60, 0, 0, 60],
              columns: [
                '\n\nPhase:  Phase1'
              ]
            }
          });
        }
          }
    ]
} );
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this answer helped, don't forget to accept :)